# Runnable Jar launched from command line: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java, javafx, executable-jar

I just finished coding an app that I want to be able to run from a double-click on the jar created.

After trying a few times and it not succeeding, I decided to try and run it from the command line (my computer is running MacOS Big Sur), using the following line:

```
java -jar rigel.jar
```

I get the following error that I absolutely don't understand:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

My IDE compiled using java 13 (I added the path to javafx in my run configurations - VM arguments on Eclipse), and my JDK version is 15.0.2.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps when you built your jar you didn't include the javafx dependencies?

Comment: could you execute it with `-Djavafx.verbose=true` flag in order to get some further details?

Comment: java -jar rigel.jar -Djavafx.verbose=true yields exactly the same output

Comment: the flag should be before , if not, is taken as a parameter for your main() method

Comment: Oh right, my bad. The output is now the same with the exception of these two lines being added at the very beggining: 

`WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid URL for class:     jar:rsrc:javafx.graphics.jar!/com/sun/glass/utils/NativeLibLoader.class
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid URL for class: jar:rsrc:javafx.graphics.jar!/com/sun/glass/utils/NativeLibLoader.class`

Comment: when creating the jar, did you include the `jfxrt.jar` library?

Comment: When creating your fat/uber jar file, did you use the JavaFX SDK (from Gluon), or the the jars from Maven Central? If the former, then the problem most likely is you did not include the _native code_ needed by JavaFX.

Comment: @aran no I didn't, how should I do that?

Comment: @slaw it sounds like it's the former, but I don't know how to include it. Could you explain how to do it on eclipse?

Comment: Not sure. You can try telling Eclipse to include files in the `bin` directory of the JavaFX SDK.